# Strong Paramaterのエラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ユーザーがsubmitして、パラメーターが以下のハッシュの形でコントローラーに届いています。

{"review"=>{"star"=>"3","comment"=>"ok"},"commit"=>"登録","id"=>"1"}

しかし、param is missing or the value is empty: review
とreviewが空であると怒られます。。
なぜでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
controllers/articles_controller.rb

def show
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
    @review.save
end

private

def review_params
  params.require(:review).permit(:star, :comment)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コントローラーのメソッドがshowになっています。
通常はcreateかupdateを使うはずです。

参考までにscaffoldを使えばたぶんこうなるだろうと思われるコードを載せておきます。

```
def create
  @review = Review.new(review_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @review.save
      format.html { redirect_to @review, notice: 'Review was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @review }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @review.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @review.update(review_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @review, notice: 'Review was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @review }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @review.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

### EDIT

> この処理をcreateメソッドをとして利用する場合は、showメソッドにはどう対応させるのがベスト・プラクティスなのでしょうか？

Railsチュートリアルの[10.3.2マイクロポストを作成する](http://railstutorial.jp/chapters/user-microposts?version=4.0#sec-creating_microposts)が参考になるかと思います。

StaticPagesControllerのhomeをArticlesControllerのshowに、MicropostsControllerのcreateをReviewsControllerのcreateとして考えるとおそらく答えに近くなるはずです。

ただし、この話は最初の質問（Strong Paramaterのエラー）とは別のテーマになってくるので、あまり深入りしないようにします。
自分でやってみてわからない点があれば、新しい質問を立てる方が良いと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！教えていただきとても嬉しいです。
私はView(show.html.erb)に対応しているメソッドはshowであるからそのViewに関することは全部showに書いてしまおうと思ってしまうのですが、
この処理をcreateメソッドをとして利用する場合は、showメソッドにはどう対応させるのがベスト・プラクティスなのでしょうか？